# Foreach loop, is it faster to derive the iterated collection outside the loop statement?

Tags: c#, foreach, iteration, enumerable

Which approach is faster or do both compile to the same IL?

```
        var myCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"a", "aa"}, {"b", "bb"}, {"c", "bb"}};
        foreach (var uniqueItem in myCollection.Values.Distinct())
        {
            //do something
        }

        var myCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "a", "aa" }, { "b", "bb" }, { "c", "bb" } };
        var uniqueItems = myCollection.Values.Distinct();
        foreach (var uniqueItem in uniqueItems)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Release* mode both yield the same *IL* and the performance will be the same (assuming the *uniqueItems* variable is not used later).

In debug you'll see another assignment before starting the *foreach*.

**Edit** - Generated IL

```
private static void V1(Dictionary<string, string> myCollection)
{
    foreach (var uniqueItem in myCollection.Values.Distinct())
    {
    }
}
```

Will compile into:

```
.method private hidebysig static void V1(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, string> myCollection) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] string uniqueItem,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<string> CS$5$0000,
        [2] bool CS$4$0001)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: nop 
    L_0002: ldarg.0 
    L_0003: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2/ValueCollection<!0, !1> [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, string>::get_Values()
    L_0008: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Distinct<string>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
    L_000d: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0> [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>::GetEnumerator()
    L_0012: stloc.1 
    L_0013: br.s L_001e
    L_0015: ldloc.1 
    L_0016: callvirt instance !0 [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<string>::get_Current()
    L_001b: stloc.0 
    L_001c: nop 
    L_001d: nop 
    L_001e: ldloc.1 
    L_001f: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
    L_0024: stloc.2 
    L_0025: ldloc.2 
    L_0026: brtrue.s L_0015
    L_0028: leave.s L_003a
    L_002a: ldloc.1 
    L_002b: ldnull 
    L_002c: ceq 
    L_002e: stloc.2 
    L_002f: ldloc.2 
    L_0030: brtrue.s L_0039
    L_0032: ldloc.1 
    L_0033: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    L_0038: nop 
    L_0039: endfinally 
    L_003a: nop 
    L_003b: ret 
    .try L_0013 to L_002a finally handler L_002a to L_003a
}
```

As can be seen the call to *distinct* is in *L_0008* and no code jumps there or above it meaning it is called just once.

Comment: In IL will that additional assignment in Debug mode be made once regardless of the number of iterations?

Comment: Yes, it stores the value of *myCollection.Values.Distinct()* on the stack without calling the method again.

Comment: one more question, what do mean with "assuming the uniqueItems variable is not used later". Does it have to do with the enumerator?